# How to make tile even

Tags: tile, subfloor

We have vinyl plank flooring throughout the house and is directly on the subfloor. We want to add tile to a bathroom but adding cement board on top of the subfloor and the height of the tile would make a large difference in flooring heights. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance of finding vinyl plank flooring that looks like tile?  A decent height difference can lead to stub toes or tripping/slipping if not watching.

Answer (score 1):

Place a floor transition strip that ramps up to and down from tile flooring to wood flooring. Transition strips, typically made of wood or thin aluminum You cut to length. These can be gotten from your favorite box store. Normally they are placed under the center of the door entering the room.